# Place Autocomplete Android | How to get the Photo of location?

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I have implemented **Place Autocomplete** but it doesn't providing me the **Photos** array.

Please help me out.
Suggestions really appreciated.
Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: photos array? "Autocomplete" (you probably mean `AutoCompleteTextView` ?) does not have any photos array

Comment: @pskink No, I am talking about https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autocomplete responses don't include photos, just a handful of key information like name and Place ID ([see the docs](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_results) for the full set of fields).  To get more detailed information like photos you need to make a [Place Details Request](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) using the Place ID from the Autocomplete response.