# How can I retrieve an image of a place from Google Places API?

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I am building an app that uses Places API.  I've included the PlacePicker widget.  When the user selects a place, the app extracts data about it, such as its address, phone number, and name.  I haven't been able to find a way to request an image associated with the place.  If anyone knows, please help.  Thanks.

Comment: Please see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174683/place-autocomplete-android-how-to-get-the-photo-of-location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey try this which help me to retrieve photos [link](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos)

You have to create url like this for image https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CnRtAAAATLZNl354RwP_9UKbQ_5Psy40texXePv4oAlgP4qNEkdIrkyse7rPXYGd9D_Uj1rVsQdWT4oRz4QrYAJNpFX7rzqqMlZw2h2E2y5IKMUZ7ouD_SlcHxYq1yL4KbKUv3qtWgTK0A6QbGh87GB3sscrHRIQiG2RrmU_jF4tENr9wGS_YxoUSSDrYjWmrNfeEHSGSc3FyhNLlBU&key=AIzaSyBly7LrT35O-6tgq1z8wu38tfTuyiDPsCg

Here URL is https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?

maxwidth,photoreference,maxhight is get from google place api
and key is your google api key

Comment: Would you mind posting an example of how that would look?  I'm having trouble understanding it.

Comment: First you get photo_reference from place search and then pass this all data in this aoi

Comment: you get photos array in place search api